# Let $E_1, E_2$ be intermediate fields of the extension $K\subseteq F$. Then $\mathrm{tr.d.} (E_1E_2/K) \geq \mathrm{tr.d.} (E_i/K)$ for $i=1,2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to prove this:
Let $E_1, E_2$ be intermediate fields of the extension $K\subseteq F$. Then we have followings:

1. $\mathrm{tr.d.} (E_1E_2/K) \geq \mathrm{tr.d.} (E_i/K)$ for $i=1,2$;
2. $\mathrm{tr.d.} (E_1E_2/K) \leq \mathrm{tr.d.}(E_1/K) + \mathrm{tr.d.}(E_2/K)$.

Definition: Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$. A **transcendence base** of $F$ over $K$ is a subset $S$ of $F$ which is algebraically independent over $K$ and is maximal (with respect to set-theoretic inclusion) in the set of all algebraically independent subsets of $F$.

Definition: Let $F$ be an extension field of $K.$ The **transcendence degree** of $F$ over $K$ (denoted $\mathrm{tr.d.}F/K$) is the cardinal number $|S|$, where $S$ is any transcendence base of $F$ over $K.$

(Related) theorem: If $F$ is an extension field of $E$ and $E$ an extension field of $K,$ then 
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{tr.d.}F/K=(\mathrm{tr.d.}F/E)+(\mathrm{tr.d.}E/K).
\end{equation*}

Does anyone have idea how to prove 1 and 2? Thank you.

Comment: $E_1E_2$ contains both $E_1$ and $E_2$ so isn't part 1 immediate? For part 2 let $S_1$, $S_2$ be transcendence bases of $E_1/K$ and $E_2/K$ respectively. Show that $E_1E_2$ is algebraic over $K(S_1\cup S_2)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes part 1 is immediate. I am not quite following showing $E_1E_2$ is algebraic over $K(S_1\cup S_2).$ How showing it is algebraic proves the statement? Thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Now I get your point! Thanks.

Comment: Good. Feel free to post the argument as an aswer. That way you can get more feedback on your solution.